# Is there a foreach method in nightmarejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, nightmare

I am trying to automate liking all the posts of a facebook page using my facebook account in nightmarejs.

I am able to login to the account, like the facebook page. But I am not able to like all the posts of a page. Because all the like button holds a single class UFILikeLink. So it would be nice if nightmarejs has foreach statement or is there any other way to do this?

```
var nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = new nightmare()
nightmare
  .viewport(800, 1600)
  .goto('https://www.facebook.com/login')
  .on('page-title-updated',function(title){
    console.log(title);
  }).inject('.js','jquery.js')
  .type('#email', 'username')
  .type('#pass', 'password')
  .click('#u_0_2')
  .wait(10000)
  .goto('https://www.facebook.com/cocacolaindia')
  .click('.PageLikeButton')
  .wait(5000)
  .screenshot("linkedin.png")
  .click('.UFILikeLink')
  .screenshot('fb1.png')
  .run(function() { console.log('Done!') });
```

Comment: Maybe you could use it with `async` and make a `foreach`.

Comment: But i need to return the collection of the posts in a array or something to loop over it and like each posts. Any idea to do it?

Comment: How much money do you expect to make by having a robot for liking post you tell it to????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the nightmarejs function `evaluate` to click like on all posts in the browser's scope.

```
nightmare
  .viewport(800, 1600)
  .goto('https://www.facebook.com/login')
  .on('page-title-updated',function(title){
    console.log(title);
  }).inject('.js','jquery.js')
  .type('#email', 'username')
  .type('#pass', 'password')
  .click('#u_0_2')
  .wait(10000)
  .goto('https://www.facebook.com/cocacolaindia')
  .click('.PageLikeButton')
  .wait(5000)
  .screenshot("linkedin.png")
  .evaluate(function(){
    $('.UFILikeLink').each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
  })
  .run(function() { console.log('Done!') });
```